# ajax with xhr cannot run success callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am writing a html page which uses ajax with **xhr** to upload a form data（including text and files）to the nodejs server.
 But after nodejs server receives the data and send back a string "1" to the frontend.The js code cannot run its success callback function.

```
function show_status(status) {
     alert(status);
     if (status == '1') {
         $('#status').text('Add game succeed!！');
     } else {
         $('#status').text('Add game failed!！');
     }
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#addformonline').submit(function(e) {
         $('#status').text('');
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'text',
             xhr:function() {
                 myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                 return myXhr;
             },
             data: new FormData($('#addformonline')),
             success: show_status,
             error: function(){alert('error');}
          });
          return false;
       }); 
  });
```

Comment: may be its because of the return type from server ?

Comment: @Deeptechtons nope, the value returned from the server is a string---"1".